# Keyboard isn't being disabled even after disabling it

Tags: keyboard, asus

My keyboard is not being disabled even after using xinput float/disable  and troubleshooting it. I am  using Ubuntu os in Asus gaming laptop as many keys are automatically clicking on its own and some are not even working.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1479851/edit) your question and add more details like what version of Ubuntu you are using.  Also, do you know if your system is using X11 or Wayland?  There also may not be a way to disable the keyboard via software to where you might have to open up the laptop and disconnect the keyboard from the motherboard, but that will probably be more work than what it is worth.